# ¿Por que me marca error al crear la funcion textoAsterisco?

Tags: javascript

¿Por que me marca error al crear la funcion textoAsterisco?

```javascript
 1 | function crearCadena(delimitadorIzquierda, delimitadorDerecha, 
 2 | cadena) {
 3 | return delimitadorIzquierda + cadena + delimitadorDerecha;
 4 | }
 5 |
 6 | let textoAsteriscos = crearCadena.bind(this,'*','*')
 7 | let textoGuiones = crearCadena.bind(this,'-','-')
 8 | let textoUnderscore = crearCadena.bind(this,'_','_')
 9 |
10 | function textoAsteriscos(cadena){return '*'+cadena+'*'}
11 | function textoGuiones(cadena){return `-${cadena}-`}
12 | function textoUnderscore(cadena){return`_${cadena}_`}
13 | 
14 | console.log(textoAsteriscos('Hola'))
15 | console.log(textoGuiones('Hola'))
16 | console.log(textoUnderscore('Hola'))
```

> Al ejecutarlo tanto en Quokka como en la consola de google me sale el siguiente error en la linea 6. Pero si elimino la palabra texto tanto de la función como de console.log() funciona bien.

```
​​​​​​​​​​Quokka 'homework.js' (node: v16.14.2)​​​​
Failed to instrument homework.js 
    
> 6 | function textoAsteriscos(cadena){return '*'+cadena+'*'} 
    |          ^ SyntaxError: Identifier 'textoAsteriscos' has already been declared (6:9) 
  7 | function textoGuiones(cadena){return `-${cadena}-`} 
  8 | function textoUnderscore(cadena){return`_${cadena}_`}
```

Comment: El problema es que no puedes tener una variable y una función que ambas se llamen `textoAsteriscos` dentro del mismo scope. Ahi claramente dice que el error es que textoAsterisco ya ha sido declarada... Cambiale el nombre o a la variable o a la funcion

Comment: si, lo pbrobe pero al cambiarle de nombre deja sin efecto a la linea 3

Comment: Bueno... si saca error luego, ya es otro error distinto, el error actual que planteas se soluciona cambiando el nombre de la variable o de la función. Que otro error sale después? que significa "deja sin efecto"? De hecho tu código funcionaría perfectamente sin las lineas de la 1 a la 8. porque ni siquiera estás haciendo uso de ellas

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahi pude saber xq es. Resulta ser que yo declaro una variable y en la linea 10 declaron una funcion con el mismo nombre y resulta que en javaScript fuera de los valores primitivos todo es un objeto, entonces en la linea 6 declaron un objeto variable y en la 10 un objeto funcion, ambos trabajan de forma diferente pero son objetos y no se pueden llamar igual.

Comment: Considera aceptar mi respuesta como válida en  StackOverflow. Me alegra que mi solución te haya servido. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente estás intentando hacer algo de 2 formas distintas pero las estás  juntando en un solo código, puedes usar el bind o la funcion normal.

Usando el bind:

```js
function crearCadena(delimitadorIzquierda, delimitadorDerecha, cadena) {
   return delimitadorIzquierda + cadena + delimitadorDerecha;
}

let textoAsteriscos = crearCadena.bind(this,'*','*')
let textoGuiones = crearCadena.bind(this,'-','-')
let textoUnderscore = crearCadena.bind(this,'_','_')

console.log(textoAsteriscos('Hola'))
console.log(textoGuiones('Hola'))
console.log(textoUnderscore('Hola'))
```

O usando las funciones

```js
function textoAsteriscos(cadena){return "*"+cadena+"*";}
function textoGuiones(cadena){return `-${cadena}-`}
function textoUnderscore(cadena){return`_${cadena}_`}

console.log(textoAsteriscos('Hola'))
console.log(textoGuiones('Hola'))
console.log(textoUnderscore('Hola'))
```

Pero actualmente tienes las 2 dentro del mismo código y con el mismo nombre, por eso el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahi pude saber xq es. Resulta ser que yo declaro una variable y en la linea 10 declaron una funcion con el mismo nombre y resulta que en javaScript fuera de los valores primitivos todo es un objeto, entonces en la linea 6 declaron un objeto variable y en la 10 un objeto funcion, ambos trabajan de forma diferente pero son objetos y no se pueden llamar igual.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada ;)

Comment: como marco la respuesta como aceptada? disculpen soy nuevo jajaja

Comment: En mi respuesta , a la izquierda veras la opción... Es un "chulo", marca de verificación o "palomita" (se le llama de distintas maneras)

Answer (score -1):

Cuando introduzcas textos, los has de introducir con comillas dobles, las comillas que utilizas, son de edición de texto especial con caracteres y funciones a incrustar...

Intenta-lo ahora ya que te comento que es de cómo declaras los simbolos con comillas simples y comillas dobles...

```
function crearCadena(delimitadorIzquierda, delimitadorDerecha, cadena) {
   return delimitadorIzquierda + cadena + delimitadorDerecha;
}

let textoAsteriscos = crearCadena.bind(this,"*","*");
let textoGuiones = crearCadena.bind(this,"-","-");
let textoUnderscore = crearCadena.bind(this,"_","_");

function textoAsteriscos(cadena){return "*"+cadena+"*";}
function textoGuiones(cadena){return "-" +'${' + cadena + '}'+"-";}
function textoUnderscore(cadena){return "_" + '${' + cadena + '}'+"_";}

console.log(textoAsteriscos("Hola"));
console.log(textoGuiones("Hola"));
console.log(textoUnderscore("Hola"));
```

Comment: Esta solución no tiene nada que ver con el error

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahi pude saber xq es. Resulta ser que yo declaro una variable y en la linea 10 declaron una funcion con el mismo nombre y resulta que en javaScript fuera de los valores primitivos todo es un objeto, entonces en la linea 6 declaron un objeto variable y en la 10 un objeto funcion, ambos trabajan de forma diferente pero son objetos y no se pueden llamar igual.

Comment: Al igual que lo de las comillas no es xq de esa forma se pueden invocar de diferentes maneras las variable del mismo ambito lexico